# hash of libgmp.so changes automatically

Tags: c, linux, hash, shared-libraries, gmp

I am using libgmp.so.3.3.3 in my application on RHEL 5.3. From my application I am taking the hash of /usr/lib64/libgmp.so.3.3.3 through sha512sum utility. My requirement is that the hash of gmp should match the hash of gmp when it was first installed otherwise it exits with an error.

When I run my applications a few times, suddenly it appears the hash of libgmp.so.3.3.3 changes and my application exits. When I re-install the gmp, it starts to work fine again as the hash matches with the one hard coded in my application.

I want to know that whether this is a known problem? Does hashes of .so files on hard drive changes automatically or am I dealing some undefined behavior?

Regards

Comment: Are you hashing before or after loading the library with dlopen? Why do you need a revision with an exact hash?

Comment: I am hashing the library in constructor function and lets say its a compulsion of my application to check hash of gmp before it gets further.

Comment: How are you hashing the library? Are you running a hash function on the file libgmp.so.3.3.3?

Comment: yes I am running hash function on the file libgmp.so.3.3.3

Comment: May it be possible that either your hard disk drive or your random access memory is corrupt? Consider running tests on both of them.

Comment: It is also important to note that I am using virtual machine.

Comment: Can you try to reproduce the problem and run the diff program on right and the corrupted version of the library? Does it yield any differences?

Comment: I'll try to replicate it.

Comment: Use also `strace` on your application